# Kittens ringworm got black during treatment

Tags: cats, medicines

My two months old kitten was diagnosed with ringworm last week. I’ve been treating her since with Nizoral shampoo, Nizoral cream, rarely lamisil cream, and sometimes some turkish cream the vet has given me. I apply on his coat the cream 2-3 time/day. However yesterday i gave him a nizoral bath and then let him sit in the sun ( i was told its antifungal, later i applied a cream and the spots turned into very small blisters then got black. Is it a healing process? Should i be concerned?[image]

Comment: Welcome to pets.SE! I am not common with ringworms, please can you say a sentence about the picture? I do not know what I am intended to see there :)